# WordPress pagination 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, pagination

Have two custom post types that I'm looping through on a page called news-events. When I go to paginate the results and click on a relevant page I get the 404 page. Have gone through changing permalinks and it still doesn't work. Also understand flushing permalinks and have done this also. The pagination code is also below but I don't think it's that as it works perfectly for the search page. Could it be .htaccess?

Query code is:

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => array ( 'news', 'events') );
    query_posts($args); ?>
```

Pagination code is:

```
if( is_singular() )
    return;

global $wp_query;

/** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/** Add current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

/** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
}

if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
}

echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

/** Previous Post Link */
if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

/** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>';
}

/** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
sort( $links );
foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
}

/** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
}

/** Next Post Link */
if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Could be two things:

1. Might need to use paginate_links function.
2. You are not pulling in the paged attribute.

One:

See the [Paginate Link Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links).

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```

---

or two: See the [Pagination Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

You should do the following:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'paged' => $paged
);

query_posts($args);
?>
```

**$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;** is the important line.